# How to dynamically build json from the database rows?

Tags: python, json, pyodbc

I want to dynamically build the json. Data in the back end database table looks like below for one customer. ('grpnm' and 'description' from below can be different for other customer)

```
custid | grpnm | description | quantity | rate | amount
1 | toys | abc | 100 | 5.5 | 550
1 | toys | def | 10 | 4 | 40
1 | kitchen| abc | 5 | 3 | 15
1 | kitchen | def | 20 | 4.5 | 90
1 | bedroom | xyz | 10 | 5 | 50
```

I have tried creating the dictionary but getting error and no luck with final JSON response

```
custid = 1
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
# get distinct grpnm for given customer
cursor.execute("select distinct grpnm from table where custid=?", custid)
data = cursor.fetchall()
for x in data:
    results_ps = {}
    out = []

    cursor.execute("SELECT description,quantity,rate,amount FROM table where custid=? and grpnm=?", custid, x)
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    for row in cursor:
#        print(row)
        out.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
    results_ps[x] = out   # TypeError: unhashable type: 'pyodbc.Row'
    #print(out)
    print(results_ps)

summary = json.dumps(results_ps, indent=4)
print(summary)
```

So based on the custid passed through api, the expected json format for response should as:

```
"summary": {
            "toys": [{
                "description": "abc",
                "quantity": 100,
                "rate": 5.5,
                "amount": 550
            },
            {
                "description": "def",
                "quantity": 10,
                "rate": 4,
                "amount": 40
            }],
            "kitchen": [{
                    "description": "abc",
                    "quantity": 5,
                    "rate": 3,
                    "amount": 15
                },
                {
                    "description": "def",
                    "quantity": 20,
                    "rate": 4.5,
                    "amount": 90
                }
            ],
            "bedroom": [{
                    "description": "xyz",
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "rate": 5,
                    "amount": 50
                }],
            "toysSubtotal": "",
            "kitchenSubtotal": "" ,
            "bedroomSubtotal": ""
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a `pyodbc.Row` object. 
Dictionary keys must be hashable. Immutable objects like string, int, tuple, implement the hash protocol.

Use the `grpnm` attribute of `x` which if it's a primitive should be hashable.

```py
results_ps = {}

for x in data:
    # ...
    results_ps[x.grpnm] = out
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation @OluwafemiSule. x.grpnm worked , but now I'm getting only the last list (in our case bedroom list) in the response (and not the kitchen and toys list). Am I missing something in code ?    And how do I get full json response under "summary" dictionary.

Comment: move the initialisation of the dictionary outside of the loop

Comment: Thanks a lot @OluwafemiSule.Initilization of dict outside the loop worked. 
Moving further I had a need to pass the value for one of the column (by putting into variable and use the variable in rest of program) out of the selected columns in cursor.execute query.

Comment: @more09 - That is a different issue. You should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @GordThompson , sure will post a new question. Since it was related to same flow of code, so continued the discussion here.

Comment: @more09 - Your new question can include a link to this question for context.